# Temporarily enable GCP Administrator Privileges on a dated computer mostly locked behind a group policy?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, group-policy

So I have an older computer (Its running windows 10 but its using the same system, settings, and group policy it had like 4 years ago) and I want to gain temporary full administrator access (I want to repurpose it) but mostly everything is locked behind system settings.

I cant do anything, most System32 Elevated Applications are disabled (Even the command prompt says its blocked)
[image]

I cant use regedit, and theres a BIOS-Level lock aswell, that requires an administrator password.
[image]

So far, I figured out how to access my C: drive (Its normally blocked, but I set a shortcut file to the C: root, and I can go in, I can even get into System32 and run some applications.

Ive even gone as far as to use exploits on this device, but nothing works.

This computer is absolutely useless because I cant do anything on it. I cant install applications, I cant run applications (Well, except a few, like chrome, allowing me to ask this question here)

I wanted to use this computer as a work device but I cant do anything on it.

I cant even reset it either. (The Shift+ debug panel on startup is also blocked somehow, it has a similar message to the one in previous things).

PS: Most of the snap-in applications and editors are also blocked, such as the Local Policy editor:
[image]

Ive tried everything I can, and Im out of options. I would appreciate any help, as I really dont wanna just leave this computer doing nothing forever, and its driving me up the wall.

Comment: What exactly is your question.  In order to use any of those functions you will have to manually enable them as an Administrator

Comment: @Ramhound Thats exactly my question. If Im completely locked out, what am I supposed to do? Throw the computer in a firepit and give up? Sure as hell not

Comment: Format the drive and reinstall Windows.  If it’s properly licensed and activated, once reinstalled, Windows will automatically be activated.  You will have to find a way to reset the password BIOS.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I should specify, it's a Laptop. I've formatted plenty of external drives, but never an internal drive (Especially one in a laptop)

Comment: Open the laptop, remove and replace  the drive,  the boot order should allow you to reinstall Windows.  Most group policies can be modified by importing a registry key.  If your able to do that is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask the system administrators that installed the laptop to format it for you so you can use it again. They can do so by going into the bios using the password they'll know and reinstall windows by booting from USB.

If this is impossible because the person who set it up is not available and you really do need to hack into the laptop, there are steps you can do. But please understand, if the people who setup this block are still available to you, what you are about to do is highly illegal and can get you fired.

So, assuming that this is legal and you tried every other means to gain access to this laptop through official channels and there are none, this is what you can do:

Open up the laptop, find the BIOS battery or CMOS clear jumper and clear it to gain access to the BIOS. You basically reset it to defaults, which removes the password.

Once the BIOS is accessible, you can use it to boot from a USB stick. Boot from a Windows 10 Install USB stick, which you can download a tool from, by searching for Media Creation Tool Windows 10, and download it directly from Microsoft.com. After you made the USB stick, boot from it and during the install, delete all partitions from your main internal HDD and select the empty space so windows will create the necessary partitions on that space and install windows to it.

Once done, you got yourself a fresh install with all rights. The laptop is not domain joined, so you cannot access any network stuff until the laptop is back into the domain, which will get the group policies back that lock the laptop up, so the laptop should not go back into the domain again, but that's probably not what you want anyway, otherwise you are already into illegal territory if you attempt to reinstall windows when the company sys admins are able to do that for you anyway.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this out. I heard something along these lines a while back, but I didn't think much of it, but it makes sense. I have some information on the internal drive I don't want to lose, but until I can get it out, I can at least bypass the bios and dual boot on Linux or something other for the moment.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are in the BIOS and you can boot from the windows 10 install screen, try the following. When you are at the first screen in the setup, press SHIFT-F10 to open a command prompt. From here, you can copy files to an external drive before formatting windows. Keep in mind, in this cmd prompt, your C drive is likely going to be D. Use DiskPart list disk, select disk x list volumes to find out which letter it has.

Comment: Oh! I've never heard of that anywhere before, thanks a ton, I'll definitely try that out. (If the command prompt isn't blocked, hopefully)

Comment: In windows setup, cmd runs completely standalone, so no, the prompt is not blocked. I have a windows 10 setup stick with me always so I can hack into any computer (legally) if I really need to.

Comment: That makes me wonder if I can use it with old GCP commands to just remove the local policy (Unless it's not administrator enabled, in which case, moving files is about the only thing I could do)

Comment: You can modify the registry, yes

Comment: The setup environment is very much shielded off from the main installation. You can interact with it upto a certain point but you really need to know what you are doing. Given that you will be "hacking" the installation to get some functionality back, it is going to be far easier to reinstall windows and backup files, and its going to be faster too.